# I can't get keytool for login Facebook on Windows

Tags: java, android, windows, facebook, keytool

When I get keytool for login Facebook, I can't get it.

```
'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: keytools is a program that comes with java jdk. Check if you have java jdk installed and add the <javaHome>\bin path to your PATH variable

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to get `Key Hash`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Add code to print out the key hash
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

Comment: Thanks you, I used tool and get it easily.

Comment: @ToanNguyenDuc If my answer solved your issue  then accept this answer and close your question so that if someone else having same issue it might be useful to them.

Answer (score 0):

Abive code will run successfully if [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/source/) is installed on the pc and the working directory is bin folder of the JRE.

```
   C:\Program Files\Java\jre<version_number>\bin>
```

***version_number*** depends on installed version of *JRE*. Download openssl and give the absolute path of the openssl executable. Sample code is shown below

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | "C:\Users\Anand\Documents\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\Users\Anand\Documents\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" base64
```